# Tkinter: frames (?) moving around

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've got a little Tkinter GUI script which I'm kind of happy with, with one exception: my frames seem to move about during the runtime, depending on the size of text being shown in one of the frames. It goes from this:

[image: Start]

... to this:

[image: Middle]

... and this:

[image: End]

... depending on the selection in the listbox, i.e. the amount of text being shown in `info_message`. This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

""" Layout
            dice_frame (1,1)    list_frame(1,2)     info_frame (1,3)
            ref_frame (2,1-3)
"""

from tkinter import *
import random
import pandas as pd

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("RP")
root.geometry('500x503')
root.resizable(0, 0)

# ----------------------------------- Dice ------------------------------------


def dice_1():
    """ 2d6 generator without modifiers """

    dice_result = random.randrange(1, 6) + random.randrange(1, 6)
    dice_main.config(text=dice_result)


def dice_2(widget_1, widget_2):
    """ Creature 2d6 dice with skill modifier """

    dice_result = random.randrange(1, 6) + random.randrange(1, 6)
    text = widget_2.cget('text')
    if text != '±0':
        modifier = int(text)
    else:
        modifier = 0
    widget_1.config(text=dice_result + modifier)

# Dice widgets
dice_frame = Frame(root, bd=5)
dice_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

dice_label = Label(dice_frame, text='Dice', justify=CENTER)
dice_label.pack()

dice_main = Button(dice_frame, text='2d6', command=dice_1, height=2, width=2,
                   font=('TkDefaultFont', 10))
dice_main.pack()

# ------------------------------- List & Info ---------------------------------

# Read stats and personalities from file
all_stats = pd.read_excel('Enemies.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1', sep=';',
                          keep_default_na=False, encoding='iso-8859-1')
all_traits = pd.read_excel('NPC Traits.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1', sep=';')

# Create and fill listbox
list_frame = Frame(root, bd=5)
list_frame.grid(row=1, column=2)

list_label = Label(list_frame, text='Enemies', font=('TkFixedFont', 12))
list_label.grid(row=1, column=1)

listbox1 = Listbox(list_frame, height=10, width=20)
for n in range(len(all_stats)):
    listbox1.insert(n+1, all_stats.iloc[n][0])
listbox1.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5)

# Info box for listbox selection
info_message = Message(root, width=300)
info_message.grid(row=1, column=3)


def list_selection(event):
    """ Gets selection and info/stats for info_message """

    index = int(listbox1.curselection()[0])
    stats = all_stats.iloc[index]

    info_text = str(stats[0]) + '\n'  # just the name
    for m in range(int((len(stats)-2)/2)):  # rest of the stats
        info_text += ('\n' + str(stats[4 + m*2]) + '\t' + str(stats[3 + m*2]))

    info_message.config(text=info_text)

listbox1.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', list_selection)

# -------------------------------- Load Stats ---------------------------------


def reduce(widget_1, widget_2):
    """ Function for reducing the value of a skill by 2 """

    # Gets current value
    text = widget_1.cget('text')
    if text == '±0':
        value = 0
    else:
        value = int(text)
    value += -2

    # Sets new value based on previous value
    if value > 0:
        widget_1.config(text='+' + str(value))
    elif value == 0:
        widget_1.config(text='±0')
    elif value == -2:
        widget_1.config(text='-2')
    elif value < -2:
        widget_1.config(text='X ', state=DISABLED, relief=SUNKEN,
                        disabledforeground='red')
        if widget_2 != '':
            widget_2.config(text='', state=DISABLED, relief=FLAT)


def generate_traits():
    """ Generates a random personality for a creature """
    t1 = all_traits.iloc[random.randrange(1, 10)][random.randrange(1, 10)]
    t2 = all_traits.iloc[random.randrange(1, 10)][random.randrange(1, 10)]
    t3 = all_traits.iloc[random.randrange(1, 10)][random.randrange(1, 10)]
    return [t1, t2, t3]


def load():
    """ Function for loading a creature's stats into a new window """

    # Create a new window
    top = Toplevel(bd=10)
    top.resizable(0, 0)

    # Stats based on listbox selection
    index = int(listbox1.curselection()[0])
    stats = all_stats.iloc[index]

    # Name
    name = Label(top, text=stats[0], font=('TkDefaultFont', 12))
    name.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

    # Separator line 1
    separator_1 = Canvas(top, height=15, width=300)
    separator_1.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)
    separator_1.create_line(10, 7.5, 290, 7.5)

    # Creates arbitrary number of modifier buttons, labels and associated dice
    modifiers = dict()
    skills = dict()
    dice = dict()
    for k in range(int((len(stats) - 4)/2)):
        if stats[k*2 + 3] != '':
            modifiers[k] = Button(top, text=stats[4 + k*2], command=lambda a=k:
                                  reduce(modifiers[a], dice[a]), width=1)
            skills[k] = Label(top, text=stats[3 + k*2], justify=CENTER)
            dice[k] = Button(top, width=1, text='Roll', command=lambda a=k:
                             dice_2(dice[a], modifiers[a]))
            modifiers[k].grid(row=k+3, column=1)
            skills[k].grid(row=k+3, column=2)
            dice[k].grid(row=k+3, column=3)

    # Skill padding
    padding_row = len(modifiers) + 4
    padding_button = Button(top, width=1, text=stats[1])
    padding_button.config(command=lambda: reduce(padding_button, ''))
    padding_button.grid(row=padding_row, column=1)
    padding_label = Label(top, text='Padding', justify=CENTER)
    padding_label.grid(row=padding_row, column=2)

    # Personality
    if stats[2]:
        # Separator line 2
        separator_2 = Canvas(top, height=15, width=300)
        separator_2.grid(row=padding_row + 1, column=1, columnspan=3)
        separator_2.create_line(10, 7.5, 290, 7.5)

        # Generate three random personality traits
        traits = generate_traits()
        trait_1 = Label(top, text=traits[0], justify=CENTER)
        trait_1.grid(row=padding_row + 2, column=1)
        trait_2 = Label(top, text=traits[1], justify=CENTER)
        trait_2.grid(row=padding_row + 2, column=2)
        trait_3 = Label(top, text=traits[2], justify=CENTER)
        trait_3.grid(row=padding_row + 2, column=3)

# Button for loading a creature
load_button = Button(list_frame, text='Load', command=load)
load_button.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5)

# ----------------------------- Reference sheet -------------------------------

ref_frame = Frame(root)
ref_frame.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=W)

image = PhotoImage(file='PDQ Table.gif')
ref_table = Label(ref_frame, image=image)
ref_table.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because grid layout manager determines the sizes of rows, columns according to the sizes of contained widgets.

Specifying `minsize`, `weight` (by using [`grid_columnconfigure`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method)) could help you solve your issue.

For example, try following examples (with or without `grid_columnconfigure`):

- Specifying `minsize`:

  ```
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry('500x503')

  def make_button_wider(): b['text'] += '++++++'
  Label(root, text='Dice', justify=CENTER).grid(row=1, column=1)
  Listbox(root).grid(row=1, column=2)
  b = Button(root, text='make it wider', command=make_button_wider)
  b.grid(row=1, column=3)
  Label(root, text='a'*70).grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)

  root.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=200) # <<<
  root.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=200) # <<<

  root.mainloop()
  ```
- Specifying `weight`:

  ```
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry('500x503')

  def make_button_wider(): b['text'] += '++++++'
  Label(root, text='Dice', justify=CENTER).grid(row=1, column=1)
  Listbox(root).grid(row=1, column=2)
  b = Button(root, text='make it wider', command=make_button_wider)
  b.grid(row=1, column=3)
  Label(root, text='a'*70).grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)

  root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0) # <<<
  root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0) # <<<
  root.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1) # <<<

  root.mainloop()
  ```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's because your layout is being determined by the content. You could try locking the sizes of your controls to avoid this.

For instance, note how your frame is moving when the "Option" information is set.  It's this sort of stuff that's causing your controls to get re-allocated.

Comment: Okay, so how do I do this?